# How to prevent event loop freeze on Nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nestjs

I'm trying to create asynchronous task in NestJs. I want that after one request to some controller was made, my async task start begin your long job while loop, and then the node/nest process steel able to answer other requests of other controllers.

But when the async loop begin, all the other endpoints of Nest being freeze until de async task are done.

I already tryed to use `setTimeout()`, `setInterval()`, `setIntermmediate()`, `queueMicrotask()` and `Promise.resolve()`

My code:

```
// Async task:

private checkTime(baseTime: number, startTimeStamp: number){
   while(true){
      const elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTimeStamp
      console.log(`Elapsed time: ${elapsedTime}`)
      if(elapsedTime > baseTime){
          console.log(`Time excced!`)
          break;  
      }
   }
}
```

And I already try something like that:

`queueMicrotask(() => this.checkTime(edge.baseTime, startedTimeStamp))`

`setTimeout(() => this.checkTime(edge.baseTime, startedTimeStamp), 0)`

Comment: You should be able to just use async functions for long running tasks and still be able to handle other requests.
`while(true)` sucks up memory extremely fast!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Just need I put async in my `checkTIme` ? You have some suggestions for I can "watch" something until something happen? like Stopwatch

Comment: The answer from Shahrukh could work. You can use Promises to „wait“ for something until it‘s done. What‘s your long running operation? If it’s something like loading a big file, I‘d go for Promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript [generators](https://javascript.info/generators)

Code snippet:

```
function* longTask(time = 1000) {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  // divides the long task into smaller chunks
  yield startTime;

 while (Date.now() - startTime < time) {
    // process(): excute a small chunk of the task
    // and yields the control back to the caller
    yield Date.now() - startTime;
  }

}

function completeLongTask(lt) {
  const val = lt.next();
  if (!val.done) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      completeLongTask(lt);
    }, 0);
  }
}

function triggerTask() {
  const lt = longTask();
  completeLongTask(lt);
}

triggerTask();
```

**Although the solution above works, I think you needn't use generators for your use case. See if this simpler solution works for you.**

```
function checkTime(baseTime, startTimeStamp) {
  const currentTimeStamp = Date.now();
  const elapsedTime = currentTimeStamp - startTimeStamp;
  console.log(`Elapsed time: ${elapsedTime}`);
  if (elapsedTime > baseTime) {
    console.log(`Time excced!`);
    return;
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      checkTime(baseTime, startTimeStamp);
    });
  }
}
```